# Euclids Lemma p|abc

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

I'm hoping yall can let me know if this proof looks okay.
I'm trying to prove "If p|abc then p|a or p|b or p|c"

This is what I came up with for the proof:

[image]

Comment: Close. In the second half it should be $1=sb+tp$, then multiply as you did by $c$. It would be better to quote Euclid's Lemma, $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $bc$. If $p$ divides $a$ we are done. Else $p$ divides $bc$, by Euclid's Lemma, and now we apply the Lemma again to $bc$.

Comment: oh crap totally missed that

Comment: so in the part where I said p divides bc it divides both terms on the right.  It would be better to write it as : So, by Euclid's Lemma, p divides a or p divides bc.  If p divides a we are done.  Else p divides bc by EL. Now we apply the Lemma to bc.... Then if p divides be we are done....

Comment: You got  cut off, probably pressed the Enter key. The part where you deal with $bc$ is fine. The next part is the problem, the second Bezout. As I wrote earlier, you should be using $b$, not $a$.

Comment: Now I see the complete comment, had to be away. Yes, if you have already proved Euclid's Lemma, there is no point in proving it twice more. Just **app;y** it twice, as in my suggestion and your comment,

Comment: ahh i see, so I need to add the prove for Euclid's Lemma.  Yah, we did that part in class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification and help.  Wanted to make sure I was going in the right direction.  My proof writing is weak lol.  Thank god this is the last proof course until I start my Graduate work.  I want to retake Discrete Math to get better at the core.  You know without a strong grounding in the core, the rest become difficult.